# why am I getting the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am getting the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" after page is rendered. I have applied some solution I found on stackoverflow here but I still get the same error. I have included the controller file, Product Model and router. The product-detail.ejs does render but the program crashes with the error: "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".

```js
//router:
 router.get('/products/:productId', shopController.getProduct)
// end router


//Product model:
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const p = path.join(__dirname, '../data', 'products.json')

const getProductsFromFile = (cb) => {
    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb([]);
        }
        cb (JSON.parse(fileContent))
    }) 
}

module.exports = class Product {
    constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
        this.title = title
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
        this.description = description
        this.price = price
    }

    save() {
        this.id = Math.random().toString()
        getProductsFromFile( products => { 
            products.push(this)
            fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }) 
    }

    static fetchAll(cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(cb)
    }

    static findById(id, cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(products => {  
            const product = products.find(p => p.id === id)
            cb(product)
        })
        
    }
}
//end Product Model



// index.js
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const errorController = require('./controllers/error')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000



const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin')
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop')
const aboutRoutes = require('./routes/about')


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', 'views')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)
app.use(shopRoutes)
app.use(aboutRoutes)
app.use(errorController.get404)



server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is up on port ${port}!`)
})
// end index.js
```

```html
<!-- product-detail.ejs -->
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %> 
</head>
<body>
<%- include('../includes/nav.ejs') %>
      <main class ="centered">
       <h1><%= product.title %>  </h1>
       <hr>
       <div>
      <img src="<%= product.imageUrl%>" alt="<%= product.title %>">
       </div>
       <h2><%= product.price%></h2>
       <p><%= product.description%></p>
       <%- include('../includes/add-to-cart.ejs') %>
       </main>
<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
<!-- end -->
```

> `

```js
//function
static findById(id, cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(products => {  
            const product = products.find(p => p.id === id)
            cb(product)
        })
        
}
// end function

//controller:
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    const prodId = req.params.productId
    Product.findById(prodId, product => {
        console.log(product)
        res.render('shop/product-detail', {
            product: product,
            pageTitle: product.title, // <- throws error
            path: '/products'
        })
    })
}
// end controller
```

`

Comment: Please post more details or code to understand and provide solution.

Comment: I am new on here and have been trying to load more code but I keep getting errors, can I share github link to my code?

Comment: @Vishwak , I have posted more of my code

Answer (score 0):

That error is pretty standard, it just means your product object is undefined. Use checks to make sure, it wont throw error by using optional chaining like this

```
product?.title
```

Comment: but the console.log(product) prints the product object in my VSC terminal output.  I have looked through my code and can't find where the error is.

Comment: I have edited my code and also added more code, can anyone help please? I have been on this for a week.

Comment: I added "app.use(express.json())" and "app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))",  I am still getting same error when trying to execute the "getProduct" controller.